# ¿Cómo hacer un buscador avanzado con php y mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

estoy intentando hacer un buscador, pero solo me busca una coincidencia de palabra.
La estructura de mi tabla en MySQL es el siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE `productos` (
`idProducto` int NOT NULL,
`categoria` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`codigoProducto` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`noDeParte` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`descripcion` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`marca` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`modelo` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`factor` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`contenido` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`existencias` int NOT NULL,
`precioDeCompra` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`precioUnitario` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
`observaciones` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
`ubicacion` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`fechaDeCompra` date NOT NULL,
`fechaDeRegistro` datetime NOT NULL,
`auxiliar` int NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;
```

Bien, esa es la estructura de mi tabla `productos`

Aclaro que estoy haciendo consulta a la columna 'descripcion' , aquí es donde solo me busca 1 palabra; por ejemplo, en mi tabla tengo registros como (los pondré en comillas para que lo diferencien como registros en la tabla):

```
'CARPETA / FOLDER DE CARTULINA COLOR ROSA TAMAÑO OFICIO'
'CARPETA / FOLDER DE CARTULINA COLOR ROSA TAMAÑO CARTA'
'CARPETA / FOLDER DE CARTULINA COLOR BEIGE TAMAÑO OFICIO'
'CARPETA / FOLDER DE CARTULINA COLOR AZUL TAMAÑO CARTA'
```

Y quiero buscar: 'carpeta rosa', ' carpeta azul', 'folder beige', si lo escribo de esa manera, mi consulta no arroja NADA.
El formulario que estoy usando es este, adjunto el código:

```
<?php
    require('cn/cnt.php'); // este archivo tiene la conexion a la base de datos
    if (isset($_POST['btnDescripcion'])) {
      $busquedaDescripcion = $_REQUEST['busquedaDescripcion'];

      $buscar = "SELECT * FROM  productos WHERE descripcion LIKE '%$busquedaDescripcion%'  AND auxiliar=1"; // este código es el que estoy usando
      $datos = $Oxi->query($buscar);
      
      if (mysqli_num_rows($datos) > 0) {
       $contador = 0;
       //Si la consulta arroja resultados, me los enlista en una tabla HTML
       while ($resB = $datos->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
       ?>
       <tbody>

         <tr>
             <td><?php echo $resB['codigoProducto']; ?></td>
                 <input type="hidden" name="codigoProducto" id="codigo<?php echo 
                 $resB['idProducto'] ?>" value="<?php echo $resB['codigoProducto']; ?>">
             <td class="desc"><?php echo $resB['descripcion']; ?></td>
                 <input type="hidden" name="descripcion" id="descripcion<?php echo 
                 $resB["idProducto"] ?>" value="<?php echo $resB['descripcion']; ?>">
              <td><?php echo $resB['contenido']; ?></td>
                 <input type="hidden" name="contenido" id="contenido<?php echo 
                 $resB["idProducto"] ?>" value="<?php echo $resB['contenido']; ?>">
               <td><?php echo $resB['existencias']; ?></td>
                  <input type="hidden" name="existencias" id="existencias<?php echo 
                  $resB["idProducto"] ?>" value="<?php echo $resB['existencias']; ?>">
               <td><?php echo '$'.$resB['precioUnitario']; ?></td>
                  <input type="hidden" name="precio" id="precio<?php echo $resB["idProducto"] 
                  ?>" value="<?php echo $resB['precioUnitario']; ?>">
                  <input type="hidden" name="precioCompra" id="precioCompra<?php echo 
                  $resB['idProducto'] ?>" value="<?php echo $resB['precioDeCompra']; ?>">
                      <?php
                        if ($resB['existencias'] <= 0) {                                
                            echo '<td><label class="advertencia">' . $resB['existencias'] . 
                            '</label></td>';
                            echo '<td><i class="fal fa-ban"></i></td>';
                        } else { ?>
                            <td><input type="text" name="cantidad" class="cantidad" min="1" 
                                 max="1000" value="1" required id="cantidad<?php echo 
                                 $resB["idProducto"] ?>"></td>
                            <form>                                    
                                <td><a name="add_to_cart" class="add_to_cart" id="<?php echo 
                                    $resB['idProducto'] ?>"><i class="fal fa-plus"></i></a> 
                                </td>
                            </form>
                        <?php
                        } // end else
                        ?>
                    </tr>

                </tbody>
                <?php
                $contador++;
              }
            } else {
            echo '<h2 class="advertencia">EL PRODUCTO NO EXISTE</h2>';
           }
      // end isset
      }
```

El formulario es:

```
<div class="ventas">        

    <div class="grid2">
        <form name="frmVentas" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" ">
        <label><b>NOMBRE / DESCRIPCIÓN:</b></label>
        <input type=" text" name="busquedaDescripcion" placeholder="Describa el producto" class="cajaBusqueda" required />
        <button type="submit" name="btnDescripcion" class="btnBusqueda">Buscar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Como mencioné, ¿alguien podría orientarme de qué consulta utilizar para que pueda hacer la búsqueda avanzada con varias palabras?

De antemano, muchas gracias.

Comment: El like sirve para buscar una palabra, lo que tienes que hacer según tú código es un método que reciba una lista de palabra y te retorne un string con la cantidad de likes por cada palabra a buscar luego lo concatenas al SQL para ejecutar la consulta. Aun que por seguridad deberías de utilizar statement aunque es un poco mas complejo.

Comment: Tal vez reemplezar " " con "%" antes de su busqueda?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De acuerdo a lo que necesitas es buscar palabras conpuestas:
-Buscar "Carpeta Azul" y que te muestre el producto "CAPERTA GRANDE AZUL NUEVA"
-Buscar "Carpeta Nueva" y te muestre el mismo resultado.

Una opción es dividir tu búsqueda y concatenarla.

Tu sql es:

```
$buscar = "SELECT * FROM  productos WHERE descripcion LIKE '%$busquedaDescripcion%'  AND auxiliar=1";
```

Ahora intenta esto:

```
$like="";
       $e=explode(" ",$busquedaDescripcion);
           for ($i=0; $i <count($e); $i++) 
            { 
              $like.= " AND descripcion LIKE '%".$e[$i]."%'";
            }           


$buscar = "SELECT * FROM  productos WHERE auxiliar=1 $like";
```

> Asi divides tu String para segmentar la búsqueda en las diferentes palabras que envías

Aunque para usar esto te recomiendo validar cada palabra por si sola, y validas cualquier carácter especial o raro que pueda ser perjudicial.

Comment: ¿disculpad mi ignorancia, pero en qué situación sería perjudicial al no validar la cadena?

Comment: Recuerda que es una consulta a tu base de datos, si es algo para ti no importa, de resto valida cada uno para evitar Inyección SQL, nada del otro mundo tranquilo, igual te dejo para que sepas medio que es https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL

Comment: Validando caracteres especiales y demas, hay muchas formas, solo es cuestion de colocar tu seguiridad como desees y listo :)

Comment: Me marca un error: Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, bool given in C:

Comment: Imprime $buscar y muéstranos que tiene

Comment: Así debería quedarte, te dejo un ejemplo https://3v4l.org/ALOWv

Comment: Perfecto, muchísimas gracias, ya funciona

Comment: Para eso estamos, para ayudarnos, saludos

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿por qué ? en el SELECT pones esto: $buscar = "SELECT * FROM  productos WHERE auxiliar=1 $like";     el número 1 está junto a like